# End kernel error message, Ubuntu Installation

Tags: boot, software-installation

I've been having a tough time installing Ubuntu 22.04.2.

Initially,  I get the end kernel error message. I've tried a few ways to resolving this issue but it's not looking so.

Now I don't get any message when I try to install it. I used to get the end kernel error but not anymore. ( I now get a blank screen )

I am very stressed about this issue.

Comment: You've not been specific as to what Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS product you're asking about; Ubuntu Server installs by default with the GA kernel stack ie. 5.15, Ubuntu Desktop however defaults to using the HWE kernel stack ie. 5.19, so which are you asking about?  Also did you verify your ISO prior to install? and did the install media verification complete? for your *unstated* installer used? (*different installers are available selected by ISO & you didn't specify which product let alone ISO choice*)

Comment: If you want help with a specific message (*you mention kernel error message*) we need details; ie. what 22.04.2 product & thus what kernel, and please copy/paste the actual error message into your question.

Comment: What is "*the end kernel error message*?"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.